# How to enable adding of attachment in email intent Android?

Tags: android, email, android-intent, attachment

I'm using the `email intent` to launch the email app on an Android application, but I'm wondering how the add `attachment` option can be included in this intent.

My question, is it possible to add an attachment using this intent?

This is the code I'm using to launch the email is intent is as follows:

```
         Toast.makeText(this, "email clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    "mailto","abc@gmail.com", null));
         emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "EXTRA_SUBJECT");
         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

This is how the email intent looks at the moment, but there is no option to add attachment:
[image: email intent]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriForFile);
```

Comment: So the uriForFile has to be the file path of a file within your application or is there an option so you can choose any file from the file system?

Comment: It has to be a file the other app can read.  But it needs to be a URI, not a path (you can trivially convert between the two).

Comment: I have a file path of a csv file in my application that I want to attached, `filePath` is it possible to convert this to a uri?

Comment: Use URI.fromFile to make a URI from a path.

Comment: How exactly can you use this, it would be URI.fromFile(uriPath); ?

Comment: URI.fromFile(new File(path))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68379/discussion-between-brian-j-and-gabe-sechan).

Comment: Tried this: URI.fromFile(new File(filePath)); but I get the error `The method fromFile(File) is undefined for the type URI` Maybe this is not available, I type URI. and fromFile doesn't show in prompt.

Comment: Make sure to include android.net.uri, not java.net.uri

Comment: checked the imports and the correct one is there, `import android.net.Uri;` but still no option for fromFile

Comment: Its in the docs, something else is screwed up.  Make sure you aren't importing both   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html

Comment: problem was I was using caps URI instead of Uri.